# List is keep adding the same items over again and how to make the textfield width to be fixed? and fix List adding the same items over again

Tags: unity, c#

This is the default window when opening it , it's showing gameobjects with scripts , each gameobject and the script attached to it.

[image: default window]

now the problems:

when I'm typing in the search field for example guid and it's showing the gameobjects with any script that contains in the name guid attached to them the yellow Script label is not directly above the textfields of the script's names.

the problem in this case is when I filter for example typing guid the vertical bar on the right is gone and then the textfields width is getting longer and then the yellow "Script" label is not above the textfields directly:

[image: guid filtered]

the second problem is when I type guid and it's filtering. then when I'm opening the window again and typing guid again it will remember the old results from before when I typed guid and will display them too and each time I will open the window and type guid it will keep adding the last results with the new once:

in this example it's showing the same guid results 3 times:

[image: old filtered results keep added each time opening the window like it's remembering the old results]